# Expressing numbers in cartesian form

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm stuck at these 3 questions:

Express the following in cartesian form:

(a) $sin(3+i)$

(b) $sinh(1+ \frac{\pi}{2}i)$

(c) $cosh( \frac{\pi}{4}i)$

(d) tan(i)

Please help me check my ans:

(a) sin(3)cosh(1)+icos(3)sinh(1)

(b) icosh(1)

(c)$\frac{\sqrt2}{2}$

(d) itanh(1)

Comment: Do you know how to write these expressions in exponential form?  E.g., $\sinh x=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}2$...

Answer (score -1):

Hint: Rewrite those expressions in exponential form using the following identities:

- $e^{x+iy} = e^x(\cos(y) + i \sin(y))$
- $\sin(x) = \frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2i} $
- $\cos(x) = \frac{e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}{2} $
- $\sinh(x) = \frac{e^{x} - e^{-x}}{2}$
- $\cosh(x) = \frac{e^{x} + e^{-x}}{2}$

Answer (score -1):

**01.sin(3+i)=sin(3)*cos(i)+cos(3)*sin(i)**

Note  cos(ix) = cosh(x) and sin(ix) = i*sinh(x).
subtitute the values then you can form it in u+i*v form

**=sin(3)*cosh(x)+cos(3)*i*sinh(x)**

for 02 and 03 express sinh and cosh in $e^x$ form. then solve it

- $\sinh(x) = \frac{e^{x} - e^{-x}}{2}$
- $\cosh(x) = \frac{e^{x} + e^{-x}}{2}$